# When and how are initial directories created in HDFS

Tags: configuration, hadoop, hdfs

I have a Hadoop setup in which the configured HDFS umask is 027 instead of the default one. Some of the initially created directories have correct permissions (like tmp `drwxrwxrwx`) but others such as `/home` are not usable (`drwxr-x---`).

As I'm creating this Hadoop deployments automatically and over and over again, I'm wondering when and how those directories are created to fix the problem at the right point. I know I can change the permissions after the setup but that feels like cheating.